# OpenAM Community Edition with Vue SPA / CORS Settings

Tags: openam, identity-management

##### Little rant

First of all, I have to admit that I don’t understand how Ping Identity, Forgerock and OpenAM are connected.

I have installed OpenAM with Docker to find an alternative to Keycloak and I have to say that I am currently very dissatisfied with the decision.

Setting it up is a real hassle, the documentation for the CE is not up to date I have the feeling. In the Admin UI you are sent back and forth between the old and new UI all the time and so far nothing works.

##### Question

I want to set up CORS so that I can log in with OIDC from my VUE3 application and use the SDK from OpenAM for this. The link to the settings for CORS from npm unfortunately leads nowhere, where can I find these settings? Is OpenAM Community Edition still supported at all? Is it still being developed?

Unfortunately, I can’t figure it out, maybe someone here can help me.

Best regards

I have tried to adjust the CORS settings under Configure > Global services > Cors Settings

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ForgeRock, openAM and Ping:
ForgeRock maintained openAM as open source for quite a time, but stopped maintaining the opensource version some time ago afaik. ForgeRock got merged with Ping recently, that’s why you are probably confused by that.

As openAM CE is not well maintained nowadays, I would not recommend to use the latest CE version of it. (The new ForgeRock AM versions are much better documented and do not have the old/new UI issues you describe.)

Regarding your CORS question: probably the solution for your problem would be to configure a corresponding CORS filter on Tomcat level that will take care of the CORS handling.